# Go modules of a forked projects not retrieving the correct repository version/code. What is the correct solution?

Tags: git, go, module, fork

I am working with **Golang 1.14 modules** (under ubuntu 18.04) and I came across a very frustrating topic in which I hope to find a better solution.

## Description

I have a [git repo forked](https://github.com/Vinggui/agenda) from another great work (cron). The owner of cron already replied to me saying that he likes my idea, but do not want to merge it into his work. Fine, so I created my own fork and intend to keep as a fork to reference the original work.
   After forking his work and changing to my needs, I used this new module (agenda) into my secondary module still under development.

**Important: Using a fresh repository without fork is not accepted since I'm not correctly crediting the original work, nor getting updates from it in a conventional way**

## Problem description

When I simply import my module in my codes as in

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Vinggui/agenda"
)

func main() {
    agendaService := agenda.New(agenda.WithSeconds())
    fmt.Print("Hi!\n")
    agendaService=agendaService
}
```

the Golang submodule manager does a `go get` and returns the wrong version of it, actually, the returned version is not mine, it's from the original repository messing up my compilation. However, when I manually do

```
go get "github.com/Vinggui/agenda"
```

Golang gets the correct version at my repository!

I have searched a lot about this and it seems to me that Golang does not "like" forks and searches for the more renowned repository.

## Temporary solution

The best solution I found for now is setting the following code into my go.mods

```
replace github.com/Vinggui/agenda => github.com/Vinggui/agenda v0.1.4
```

## Desired result

I wish I could just import my fork like any other module and get the correct version.

```
"github.com/Vinggui/agenda"
```

Is there anything better I can do? Why does Golang do what it's doing now?

Comment: The command `curl 'https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/!vinggui/agenda/@v/list'` reports  versions v1.0.0 and v1.2.0.  I assume that these versions are cached on the proxy because you executed `go get github.com/Vinggui/agenda` before you modified your repo.  I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Looks like this is due to the module proxy; your code builds correctly if the environment variable "goproxy" is set to "direct". When using the proxy go is retrieving  [this url](https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/%21vinggui/agenda/@v/list) which includes version 1.2.0 (the latest v1 release from the parent repo). I guess you could work around this by adding a 1.2.1 in your repo.

Comment: @Brits I thought about this option too, but this must not be the correct solution. The original repo could also update his version, and I would have a versioning race that seems incorrect for me. Nevertheless, I appreciate your input!

Comment: "the original repo could also update his version" - I dont think that would matter. I believe that @CeriseLimón is correct in that you probably ran ```go get``` (which added 1.2.0 to the cache) and then made whatever changes you did. Further releases on the parent repo should not have any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

As simple as this question may be for some, the golang proxy was actually making me confused.

When I started my agenda fork, I probably messed up with its versions, and my golang **version was below 1.13**. The recent versions have their default proxy set to a different value and my proxy repo did not work anymore.

Searching online, I understood that the google go proxy is definitive, so the only way I can think now is to actually update my version to be the latest among the proxy saved versions.

Anyhow, it helped me a lot to observe this (new to me) proxy default parameter and its functions.

Thanks again.